# Add tags in terraform based on git sha

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I've recently started working with terraform and am currently creating Azure infrastructure via the `azurerm` provider. Most objects in Azure give me the possibility to add tags, I'd like to add a tag containing the git sha of the module that I've used when applying my terraform code. I'm curious if this is possible, [the following gist](https://gist.github.com/mattmahn/f46420ba8d740cc008accfde964c2e74) shows that it is possible to extract your sha with the following code:

```
# get_sha.sh
#!/bin/bash
set -euo pipefail

echo '{"sha": "'"$(git rev-parse HEAD)"'"}'
```

```
data "external" "git_checkout" {
  program = ["${path.module}/get_sha.sh"]
}
// now use:
data.external.git_checkout.result.sha
```

If I'd then add this as field for a tag, obviously my `terraform plan` would always detect changes and propose them. Is there a way that terraform would ignore these changes if they are the only one, but include them if there is something else changing in my module?

Comment: You would need to use [lifecycle](https://www.terraform.io/language/meta-arguments/lifecycle#ignore_changes) block to ignore selective tags so that you don't see the drift in the plan. 

This also doesn't apply changes of that particular tag on subsequent "terraform apply"..

Comment: I think you always see changes in plan because the data source is valuated at runtime, a possible solution is like @harshavmb say, to ignore the tags. Be carefull, is an optimal solution if is not important for you apply a change when the module is updated. Instead if you want to update your module also if you didn't change nothing in the configuration but the remote module was updated, so you shouldn't use the lifecycle block